# How to Skip the API call using RxJS skip operator?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to skip the very first API call using the skip operator in RxJS . But I am not able to achieve that .

```
const source = of('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');

const example = source.pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('Service call triggered')), // I'm using a switchMap here to trigger the API call , tap is just for explaining the issue
  skip(1)
); 

const subscribe = example.subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```

In the above example, I'm seeing 5 `console.logs` . But I want to see only 4 `console.logs` . Could you help, please?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qug9zx?file=index.ts)

Comment: `skip` needs to be **before** `tap` to actually skip the first console log.

Comment: The operator order is important here. Try to move `skip(1)` to the top and it should work, like @AT82 mentioned

Comment: In the stackblitz I only see 4 console logs from the subscription

Comment: @ShamPooSham Good catch, seems there the order is correct, `skip` is before `tap` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
const example = source.pipe(
  skip(1),
  tap(() => console.log('Service call triggered')), 
);

const subscribe = example.subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```